# Making a prescriptionCode (variable) appear in specific format in java

Tags: java, int

sorry for the title but couldn't really express this in another way. 
So, let's say I have a variable that represents a prescription's unique code. I already know that there a total of 400 prescriptions. So for every new prescription I would like that code to change by one. The first one I want it to be 001, the second one 002 etc. I know I can just set a static int but how can I make the 0's appear in the front so it prints 001 and not just 1? I am new to java so I might be asking a really stupid question. Thanks for your time!

Comment: `System.out.printf("%03d%n", 1);` change `1` to `i` or `variable` or whatever is appropriate. `0` is the fill character, `3` is the length `d` means decimal and `%n` means newline.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can format it with Java format specifiers.
Here would be the code to do that:

```
int prescriptionCode = 1;
System.out.println(String.format("%03d", prescriptionCode));
```

The string "%03d" is the format specifier. Going backwards, "d" indicates that the value you want here is a decimal, "3" indicates that you want the value to be 3 characters long regardless of its actual length, "0" means that you want to fill the remaining space the number doesn't take up with 0's.